# Ordinal Logistic Regresion - integer dependent variable showing correlation for every data point

Tags: r, variables

I am currently trying to run a simple ordinal logistic regression comparing a data value with 5 levels against age and gender, and regardless of whether I set the "age" variable as numeric or an integer, the output displays the correlation for each different age represented in the data set and am unsure of where I am going wrong.

I have put a sample of the code below as well as the output (the full dataset is in variable 'b', I have shortened the output for all ages but you should get the idea):

```
> sex <- as.factor(b[,"sex"])
> age <- as.numeric(b[,"age"])
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> concern_infect_me <- factor(b[,"concern_infect_me"], order = TRUE, levels =c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))
> class(age)
[1] "numeric"
> m <- polr(as.factor(concern_infect_me) ~ age + sex, data = b, Hess=TRUE)
> summary(m)
Call:
polr(formula = as.factor(concern_infect_me) ~ age + sex, data = b, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
         Value Std. Error  t value
age50  0.37683    1.03091  0.36553
age51  1.01450    0.97053  1.04530
age52 -0.53497    0.81320 -0.65786
age53  0.01081    0.79643  0.01358
age54  0.34278    0.79978  0.42860
age55 -0.64086    0.79238 -0.80878
age56  0.04494    0.83026  0.05412
age57  0.05759    0.85094  0.06768
age58  0.19373    0.81740  0.23701
age59  0.22877    0.78047  0.29311
age60  0.19694    0.76059  0.25893
age61  0.35515    0.80291  0.44233
age62  0.05052    0.77313  0.06535
... #the ages erroneously go till age90
sex   -0.20434    0.09806 -2.08391

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 -2.2928  0.7026    -3.2635
2|3 -0.6617  0.6981    -0.9479
3|4  0.8395  0.6987     1.2017
4|5  1.8591  0.7006     2.6537

Residual Deviance: 4194.222 
AIC: 4288.222 
(221 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

I'm really not sure why this is causing this issue. Any other similar datasets I've run with age as a correlation variable works fine as either a numeric or integer variable.
I'm a relative novice to R and would appreciate any insight, thanks!

Comment: it looks like when you make `age` numeric you do not assign it back to the data e.g. use `age <- as.numeric(b$age)`

Comment: I'll try this, thank you!

Comment: sorry my comment should of been " use `b$age <- as.numeric(b$age)`",  so that the transform is applied to the variable **within** the data.frame